# function to select observations within ranges of one or more variables (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, data-manipulation

I have an application where I want to define a function to allow observations
to be selected from a data set according to conditions on the ranges of one
or more variables.  This is fairly simple to do in straight R code, but I would like to have a data-driven function that could take those conditions as arguments, and allow more general conditions.

Here is a simple example

```
set.seed(1234)
n <- 100
testdat <- data.frame(
            X = round(rnorm(n, mean=10, sd=3), 2),
            Y = rnorm(n, mean=8, sd=2),
            NL = sample(2:10, n, replace=TRUE)
            )
```

**using a data frame of ranges**

Say I want to select observations with `0 <= X < 10` and `0 <= Y < 8`.  I can do this as:

```
# define a handy utility function 
within <- function(x, a, b)
    (!is.na(x)) & (x >= a) & (x <= b)

# specify ranges for variables
ranges <- data.frame(X = c(0,10), Y= c(0,8))

# calculate acceptance
OK <- rep(TRUE, n)
for (col in colnames(ranges)) {
    OK <- OK & within(testdat[, col], ranges[1,col], ranges[2,col])
}
# select
testdat[OK,]
```

Demonstrate:

```
plot(Y ~ X, data=testdat, col=1+OK, pch=(15:16)[1+OK])
abline(v=ranges$X, h=ranges$Y, col="gray")
```

[image]

This is quite easy to define as a function:

```
Select <- function(x, ranges) {
    OK <- rep(TRUE, nrow(x))
    for (col in colnames(ranges)) {
        OK <- OK & within(x[, col], ranges[1,col], ranges[2,col])
    }
    x[OK,]
}
```

**using dplyr**

It is much simpler and far more flexible to do this sort of thing using `dplyr`, but I can't see how to turn this into a function that would take an arbitrary number of conditions.

Same example with `dplyr`:

```
selected <- testdat %>%
    filter( within(X, 0,10), within(Y, 0,8) )
```

or,

```
selected <- testdat %>%
    filter( X < median(X), Y < median(Y) )
```

Wanted:  a function with the following call, where `...` corresponds to additional logical expressions involving the variables in `x`

```
Select <- function(x, condition, ...) {
   # what goes here ???
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** This is an updated version of the function intended to provide a more intuitive way to add selection conditions. The conditions are passed as a list. Each list element is a vector with three elements, the column name, the lower bound, and the upper bound. Just add more elements to the list in order to add more column selection conditions. Here's the function, followed by three examples:

```
my_subset = function(data, conditions) {

  vars = sapply(conditions, function(x) x[1])
  gt = sapply(conditions, function(x) x[2])
  lt = sapply(conditions, function(x) x[3])

  data %>% 
    filter_(paste(vars, "<=", lt, collapse=" & ")) %>%
    filter_(paste(vars, ">=", gt, collapse=" & "))
}

testdat %>% my_subset(list(c("X",4,10), c("Y",10,Inf)))

iris %>% my_subset(list(c("Sepal.Width",3.2,3.5), c("Petal.Width",0,0.2)))

mtcars %>% my_subset(list(c("mpg",20,25), c("wt", 2.5, Inf), c("hp", 0, 100)))
```

**Original Answer**

Here's a dplyr function that will take any number of conditions and return the subsetted data frame. We use `paste` to put together whatever conditions are passed to the function.

```
my_subset = function(data, vars, gt=NULL, lt=NULL) {

  if(!is.null(lt)) {
    data = data %>% 
      filter_(paste(vars, "<", lt, collapse="&"))
  }

  if(!is.null(gt)) {
    data = data %>% 
      filter_(paste(vars, ">", gt, collapse="&"))
  }

  data
}
```

Now run the function on your sample data:

```
my_subset(testdat, c("X","Y"), gt=c(4,3), lt=c(8,6))
```

or

```
testdat %>% my_subset(c("X","Y"), gt=c(4,3), lt=c(8,6))
```

> ```
>      X        Y NL
> 1 7.67 5.780466 10
> 2 6.93 4.973424  5
> 3 7.87 5.656103  5
> 4 5.11 4.699798  4
> 5 5.98 4.103508 10
> 6 7.68 5.893234  7
> 7 5.83 5.752474  6
> ```

```
iris %>% my_subset(c("Petal.Width","Sepal.Length"), lt=c(0.3,4.5))
```

> ```
>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
> 1          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa
> 2          4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1  setosa
> 3          4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2  setosa
> 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
> ```

Comment: That is a very helpful anwer.  I didn't realize that `filter_` and related functions allowed a string argument.  I also like the use of `%>%` in the last example. Still, I would favor a solution that didn't separate the variable names and the lower/upper bounds into separate arguments, which makes it harder to type and harder to understand.

Comment: The standard evaluation versions of `dplyr` functions (e.g., `filter_` as opposed to `filter`) can take string arguments (see the [Non-Standard Evaluation vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) and various questions on SO).